# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where ` id` =

Tags: laravel

I'm getting the error message below.
This is my first time to use laravel.
I have no idea how I could modify my codes.

The below is my PC environement:
My PHP version: 7.4.2
Laravel version: 7.3.0
OS: Linux
MySQL version: 5.7.26

Thank you for your advice in advance!

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where ` id` = 52)
```

CommentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $params = $request->validate([
            'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts, id',
            'body' => 'required|max:2000',
        ]);

        $post = Post::findOrFail($params['post_id']);
        $post->comments()->create($params);

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', ['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('top');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'show']]);
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController', ['only' => ['store']]);
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="border p-4">
            <h1 class="h5 mb-4">
                {{ $post->title }}
            </h1>

            <p class="mb-5">
                {!! nl2br(e($post->body)) !!}
            </p>

            <section>
                <h2 class="h5 mb-4">
                    Comment
                </h2>

                <form class="mb-4" method="POST" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}">
                @csrf

                    <input name="post_id" type="hidden" value="{{ $post->id }}">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="body">
                            Context
                        </label>

                        <textarea
                            id="body"
                            name="body"
                            class="form-control {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                            rows="4"
                        >{{ old('body') }}</textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('body'))
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $errors->first('body') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Add comments
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                    @forelse($post->comments as $comment)
                    <div class="border-top p-4">
                        <time class="text-secondary">
                            {{ $comment->created_at->format('Y.m.d H:i') }}
                        </time>
                        <p class="mt-2">
                            {!! nl2br(e($comment->body)) !!}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    @empty
                        <p>No comments yet.</p>
                    @endforelse
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

[image: This is posts table from my MySQL]

Comment: There's no tables and data in your database. You probably need to run the migrations first with `php artisan migrate`

Comment: `findOrFail()`  automatically assumes your primary key column is going to be `id`. In order for this to work correctly, you should set your primary key in your model.

Comment: I have edit my question and add my MySQL photo.

Comment: @Sanae pls check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is a space in-front of `id` in your validation.

To resolve this error you have to **remove that space**

**Change**

```
'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts, id', // remove space from here
```

**to**

```
'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts,id',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I get a different error message which is here: Add [post_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Comment]. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It may sound a bit harsh, but these are really rookie mistakes @Sanae. It might be useful to watch the "from scratch" series at https://laracasts.com/. Those videos cost you about a day and guide you through how laravel works and why you get errors like these. Plus you get to build and deploy your own web app in that course :)

Comment: Thank you @Loek That might be helpful to a beginner to laravel like me. I'll check this out :)

Comment: @Sanae Go into your model "App\Comment" and add post_id to the fillable array. "protected $fillable = ['parameters', 'go', 'here'];"

Comment: It's all working now! Thanks a lot :)) @Tyler Shannon